# The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0."

Tags: c#, excel, sql-server-2008, datatable

> The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime.  There is an unknown word starting at index 0."

I am trying to import the Excel data into Sql Server db table for that I'm doing bulk insert and in my db the datatype is `date` and in Excel string.

Below is my code:

```
public static class DataTableExt
{
    public static void ConvertColumnType(this DataTable DTable, string columnName, Type newType)
    {
        using (DataColumn dc = new DataColumn(columnName + "_new", newType))
        {
            // Add the new column which has the new type, and move it to the ordinal of the old column
            int ordinal = DTable.Columns[columnName].Ordinal;
            DTable.Columns.Add(dc);
            dc.SetOrdinal(ordinal);

            // Get and convert the values of the old column, and insert them into the new
            foreach (DataRow dr in DTable.Rows)
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr[columnName].ToString()))
                {
                    dr[dc.ColumnName] = Convert.ChangeType( dr[columnName], newType);
                }
                else
                {
                    dr[dc.ColumnName] = Convert.ChangeType(DateTime.Now, newType);
                }

            // Remove the old column
            DTable.Columns.Remove(columnName);

            // Give the new column the old column's name
            dc.ColumnName = columnName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `DateTime.ParseExact()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8